# How to get value from NSArray ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have got json response like following

```
Photo = ["\image1.jpg\","\image2.jpg\","\image3.jpg\"]
```

How can i get only name from this json response.

I want output like

```
Image1.jpg
Image2.jpg
Image3.jpg
```

Without [] and "".

Comment: post your code ...

Comment: Did you (de)serialized the JSON?

Comment: No, how to de serialized json and get only name of image .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Your Photo String is not in proper format. The correct String is as follows:

```
NSString *jsonString = @"[\"\image1.jpg\",\"\image2.jpg\",\"\image3.jpg\"]";
```

Try out the below code to get image name from Your String:

```
    NSString *jsonString = @"[\"\image1.jpg\",\"\image2.jpg\",\"\image3.jpg\"]";
    NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSError *e = nil;
        NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

        if (!json) {
            NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", e);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Item: %@", json);
            for(NSString *item in json) {
                NSLog(@"Item: %@", item); 
            }
        }
```